# I need an array to print all the numbers and count their occurrence

Tags: java, arrays, count

I have an array with the numbers (2,2,2,2,4,5,9,9,11,11,12) and I need the console to print out all the numbers inbetween the min and the max and count their occurrence. ie. Number 2 occurs 4 times, number 3 occurs 0 times, number 4 occurs 1 time.

I have it semi working but it is printing too much. I understand why but cannot figure out how to do it another way.

```
    int min = 2;
    int max = 12;
    int m=0;


    for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<y.length;j++){
            if(y[j]==i){
                m+=1;
            }
            else{
                if(m>=1){
                    System.out.println(i+" "+m);
                    m=0;
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(i+" "+m);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need a doubly nested loop. Just sort the array and look for consecutive characters. That would work better.

Comment: can you explain how your code partially works?

Comment: When you say you need to print out all the characters between the min and max are you planning on excluding the min/max recurrence? And in addition to that, do you really want to do this for the whole array? You could have quite the print statement on your hands if the array gets too large. Why not set up this method to count the instances of a number x in an array?

Comment: so it needs to be every number between the min and max, and min max are inclusive.

Comment: Let's get an assumption straight:  is the array you're messing with always going to be in sorted order?

Comment: yes, always. it is probably rather simple by i've been staring at it too long.

Comment: I am just wondering **why this question is not flagged with more people since the op is just looking for a code answer?!!!**

Comment: @KickButtowski:  I'm giving the OP the benefit of the doubt here.  The hope is that an answer here will actually rise above to truly explain what the method of thinking should be as opposed to *just* posting code.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the theory behind the answer but sometimes seeing the answer actually helps me to understand it better. I believe I was almost there but just had to remove the a part of the code to another area. Sometimes you just need another view point.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain myself, for each number between the minimum and maximum you "scan" the array, if the number is found you add 1 to the counter.
After the "scan" complete you print the counter,reset the counter and continue to the next value  between the min and max.

I believe this is what you tried to do:

```
int min = 2;
    int max = 12;
    int m = 0;
    int y[] = { 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 9, 9, 11, 11, 12 };
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
            if (y[j] == i) 
                m += 1;


            }
        System.out.println(i + " " + m);
        m=0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is definitely a much closer solution to what should be happening.  Could you elaborate a bit on why this is correct?

Comment: what he tries to do in my opinion is for each number between min and max
scan the array and count the times the number is appears :)

Comment: What I meant was explain it in the answer.  This is actually a very good answer, but it's mostly code; I strongly encourage you to explain why this solution works, not just because it helps the OP gain a better understanding, but because there are others that may come across this question.  Leaving them with just a block of code is counterproductive.

Comment: @Makoto I am just wondering why this question is not flagged with more people since the op is just looking for a code answer?!!!

Comment: @Seiran it is good to point out that double for loop has bad performance which is n ^ 2

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> occurrence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < myarray.legnth; i++) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
        if (myarray[i] == j) {
            a++;
        }
    }
    occurrence.add(a);
}
```

This occurrence list now contains the occurrences; give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

In Java8 there is a simple solution, even though it may not be best, performance-wise :

```
Arrays.stream(array)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
      .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k+" "+v.size()));
```

Comment: I do not think giving out this code will be helpful **at all**

Comment: yea I can't use this as I need to do this on paper for an exam but thanks for the help

Comment: @Kick Buttowski : I don't know how you can say that, regarding the few information OP gave in the first place. That could have been helpful.

Comment: @Neumann I just expressed what I believe beside I did not vote u down. I really love your approach but at least some explanation does not kill anyone. if you see my answers, I have a lot Java 8 answers. :)